# getComputedStyle returns different background color for pseudo elements

Tags: css, dom, selenium-chromedriver, background-color, pseudo-element

I have a *pseudo-element* in dom that has a css property **background-color** of **rgb(23,171,111)**

Now, when I try to get the *CSS* property using *window.getComputedStyle* function, I get a different color **rgb(56, 147, 110)**.

```
let color = window.getComputedStyle(el, ':before').getPropertyValue('background-color')
```

Inspecting the element shows the **background-color** is set to **rgb(23,171,111)**

All other CSS properties set on the element remain unaffected.

Why is it so?

**N.B.**:- Works in **google chrome** and **firefox**. I face the issue only with **chromedriver**. All of the browsers are updated to their latest version.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What browser are you using? Can you post your code? https://jsbin.com/vutehavuxo/edit?css,js,console,output

Comment: @fubar I am using **chrome**, more precisely **chromedriver**. I am not facing any issues with **firefox**.

Comment: I didn't have any issues on Chrome 64 or Firefox 58. I don't have Chromedriver installed to test I'm afraid. If you copy the example in the snippet, does it work for you on Chromedriver?

Comment: @fubar  It will take some time for me to set up the environment for **chromedriver**. FYI, I am also not facing any issues with *google chrome*. Is there a possibility that the issue is caused due to the version of chrome used in **chromedriver**?

Comment: According to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=getComputedStyle) pseudo-elements have been supported in Chrome since v11. So to answer your question, yes. But it's unlikely you're using a browser from 2011?

Comment: @fubar but I also checked the version of chrome used in chromedriver and It is same to the version of google chrome I have installed _i.e._ 64.

Comment: I don't know anything about ChromeDriver, so I'll defer to others. It might be worth tagging your question with that too, as it seems to be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, sure. anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: @fubar I suppose the issue is with the chromedriver rendering my page. Running my test in _headless mode_ returns a different result. **rgb(48, 153, 110)**. It seems the script is returning just different shades of **green** color. But not the actual **green** color that I want.